# How Fault tolerance be implemented using Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: c#, fault-tolerance, azure-traffic-manager

Say we have 2 Azure hosted sites; one is asia (ap.test.com) and one in europe (eu.test.com) which are load balanced via Azure Traffic Manager. As this works at DNS level and user is directly connected to say my asia website (due to say low latency). Now if user got connected to the Asia website and after a while that Azure Asia data center is down, how can I get my clients automatically redirect to the European one without having to guess what to do; of course they need to re-login e.g. ideally by redirecting automatically OR by showing some error.

Do I need to write code to check my self the health of my domains and then redirect or is there some quick easy way (requiring no code)? My sites are developed in C#

Wahaj

Answer (score 0):

The best option in this case would be to make sure that you have the lowest TTL as possible so that, if customer attempts to re-connect to your site, it has to perform another DNS lookup.

Comment: Thanks but this means that even if TTL is 30 sec or so I need to write some client side code to ensure the client remains engaged, some thing like how gmail shows 'connecting to the server, retry'